# Design_Time_Address works in debugger but doesn't during unit test run

Tags: c#, wcf, design-time, unit-testing

This code works just fine when I debug unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    private ServiceHost _host;
    private Uri _baseAddress = new Uri(<code>"http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/service"</code>);
    private Inbound.Client.ServiceClient _client;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), _baseAddress);
        var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        _host.Open();
        _client = new Inbound.Client.ServiceClient();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _client.Close();
        _host.Close();           
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_ping()
    {
        PingResponse response = _client.Ping(new PingRequest { Echo = "Hi" });
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        Assert.AreEqual("Hi", response.Echo);
    }
}
```

However, when I run unit test (right click on test in VS Test Explorer, Run Selected Test) I get this error message:

```
"... System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException :
 The HTTP service located at  http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses is unavailable. ...
----> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."
```

It appears that when NUnit test runner runs the test, it cannot launch the host. I know that Design_Time_Address uri is registered in netsh during VS installation and I wonder if there should be an additional registration just for NUnit test runner.

Answer (score 2):

Design_Time_Address is associated with WcfTestClient. There is a WCF project property "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution". This property was checked. During unit test debugging WCF test client was launched. The interesting part was that `_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), _baseAddress);` initialized `host` to just launched instance of WCF test client as opposed to creating a new service host instance. When unit test ran outside of the debugger WCF test client wasn't launched and call to `ServiceHost` was simply failing.

The problem was that the service url should be

`(<code>"http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses"</code>`

as opposed to

`<code>"http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/service`

even though with default WCF scaffolding templates it is "/Service"